# how to use alias field in query ? (oracle 10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00904

If I write this query:

```
select Fname,Age*2 as Demo from Men where Demo = 5
```

then I get the error

> ORA-00904 (Demo not identified )

How I can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need "as" in Oracle.

You simply write:

```
select fname, asge*2 demo from men;
```

However you cannot use the alias in the "where"-clause.

A Quote from a post on another site:

> The technicality of it is that when
>   the where clause and the group by
>   clause are being executed, the select
>   part of the query has not run and the
>   alias has not been assigned.  Since
>   the order by is technically done after
>   the select the aliases can be used.